# Passing parameters by shell script file to expect script

Tags: shell, ssh, openssh, expect, parameter

I need to pass a paramter from a shell script under command line of ssh script

for example :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh user@servername.com "cm1+passingparameters.sh;cmd2"
```

my existing script `123.sh` which is working fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh user@servername.com "/pstools/85419/jre/bin/java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 -jar /app1/non/psoft/85419/gu1/gust/classes/SVC_TestS.jar https://decorp6-- tst4.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/v1.3/incidents userid password ssow.proxy.com port;cd /app01/nonhr/psoft/85419/gucq1/gecust;mail -s 'OTO' email@ged.com < logs.txt"

expect "password"

send "mypassword\r"

interact

expect eof
```

I want 2 scripts `a.sh` and `b.sh`

`a.sh` should be as follows (notice change from above mentioned original script `PASS b.sh after .jar`)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh user@servername.com "/pstools/85419/jre/bin/java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 -jar /app1/non/psoft/85419/gu1/gust/classes/SVC_TestS.jar PASS b.sh;cd /app01/nonhr/psoft/85419/gucq1/gecust;mail -s 'OTO' email@ged.com < logs.txt"
expect "password"

send "mypassword\r"

interact

expect eof
```

`b.sh` should be as follows

```
#!/user/ksh
 https://decorp6--tst4.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/v1.3/incidents userid password ssow.proxy.com port
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you're asking how to insert various arguments into the remote `java` command, which may be as simple as

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

if {[llength $argv] == 0} {
  puts stderr "Usage: todo fixeme"
  exit 1
}

set the_args [join $argv]

spawn ssh user@servername.com "/pstools/85419/jre/bin/java ... -jar /app1/non/psoft/85419/gu1/gust/classes/SVC_TestS.jar $the_args; ..."
...
```

And then you would run the above via something like:

```
$ whatyousaveditas https://decorp6--tst4.cu... user pass ...
```